# Laravel 10.4 with ChartJS - x-axis false text

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js, php-carbon, laravel-10

I am learning how to implement Charts in Laravel. I followed some basic instructions found on the internet and managed to connect to the DB, but in the X-axis I wanted to see the days of the week, but it displays the wrong text formatting.
I want to see Mo Tue Wen Thu Fr Sa So, but I only see the whole bar with the text [ W e d n e s d a y ] in brackets.
where am I going wrong?

ChartJSController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Picking;
use DB;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class ChartJSController extends Controller
{
        /**
     * Write code on Method
     *
     * @return response()
     */
    public function index()
    {
     
      $data=Picking::select('id', 'created_at')
      ->get()
      ->groupBy(function($data)
    
    {
        return Carbon::parse($data->created_at)->format('D');
    });
        $months=[];
        $monthCount=[];

            foreach($data as $month => $values){
                $months[]=$month;
                $monthCount[]=count($values);
        }
              
        return view('chart', ['data' => $data, 'months'=>$months, 'monthCount'=>$monthCount]);
    }
```

Chart.blade.php

```
<x-app-layout>



    <div class="py-12">
        <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-sm sm:rounded-lg">
                <div class="p-2 text-gray-900">
                {{ is_array($months) }}
                {{ is_array($monthCount) }}             



<div>
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>


<div>
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

<script>
  const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

  var _ydata='{!! json_encode($months) !!}';
  var _xdata='{!! json_encode($monthCount) !!}';

  new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: _ydata,
      datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: _xdata,
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        y: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }
    }
  });
</script>



                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</x-app-layout>
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udUGs.png)

Comment: It depends on "$months" value and on this statement: var _ydata='{!! json_encode($months) !!}';  What is the value of $months?

Comment: Yes, I know this depends on variable $months, but the variable $months come from the controller, and a think about the error is in the controller but idk where. Maybe the setting with the carbon? I don’t know

Comment: may be logging the value of $months and its JSON encode value you can see the possible reason.